# Number of pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, integer

I am trying to write a code that takes

- m. *a*, a list of integers
- n. *b*, an integer
  and returns the number of pairs (m,n) with m,n in *a* such that |m-n|<=b.

So far, I've got this

```
def nearest_pairs(a, b):
    m= []
    n= int
    num_pairs = 0
    return num_pairs

def main():
    # The nearest pairs are (1,2), (2,1), (2,5) and (5,2)

    x = nearest_pairs( [1,2,5] , 3 )
    print( "nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 3) = " , nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 3) )

    # The nearest pairs are (1,2) and (2,1)
    y = nearest_pairs( [1, 2, 5] , 2 )
    print( "nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 2) = " , nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 2) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The desired output should look like

```
>>> nearest_pairs([1,2,5],3) = 4
```

where 4 is the number of close pairs according to the restrictions. However, I get an error. Could anyone lead me to the right direction?

Comment: Let's  be real here - you don't really have anything. You wrote some boilerplate code and testcases.

Comment: `nearest_pairs(a, b)` is a silly way to write `return 0`

Comment: What are those 4 pairs in that example?

Comment: They are (1,2), (2,1), (2,5) and (5,2)

Comment: Try `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
def nearest_pairs(a, b):
    for m, n in permutations(a, 2):
        if abs(m - n) <= b:
            yield (m, n)
```

```
>>> list(nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 3))
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 5), (5, 2)]
>>> list(nearest_pairs([1, 2, 5], 2))
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

If you just want the count:

```
def nearest_pairs_count(a, b):
    c, l = 0, len(a)
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(i + 1, l):
            if abs(a[i] - a[j]) <= b:
                c += 2
    return c
```

Comment: This is _O(n²)_ though, I know of at least an _O(n log n)_ algorithm.

Comment: @poke thank you, i see where you are going with this! However, this does not answer my question. In the output I should have a counted number of pairs like nearest_pairs([1,2,5],3) = 4

Comment: @Marie_ohoho If you can't figure out how to get the length of that list I suggest doing some studying (since this  question sounds like HW).

Comment: I don't see `O(N * log(N))` solution. Both solutions are `O(N**2)`. Note: if `a` contains duplicates then `c += 2` might be incorrect.

Comment: @orlp: do you mean a solution that uses a [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) or something simpler?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Hint: sort the list first. Then for every `x` in the list, do a binary search for `b-x`. What does this tell you about the number of pairs smaller than or equal to `b`?

Comment: @orlp you probably want to search for both `(x-b)` and `(x+b)`

Comment: @orlp How about you submit this as an answer?

Comment: @poke Can't be bothered to flesh out the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yours doesn't make sense. No idea what you're trying with `len(a, b)`, but it's not even allowed, since `len` takes only one argument. And returning something just when you found the first counting pair? Here's a fix:

```
def close_pairs(l, d):
    ctr = 0
    for a,b in permutations(l, 2):
        if (a - b) <= d and (b - a) <= d:
            ctr += 1
    return ctr
```

And here's how I'd do it:

```
def close_pairs(l, d):
    return sum(abs(a-b) <= d for a, b in permutations(l, 2))
```